# Populate a list of Objects (With Linq?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do the following,

```
    IList<RoleViewModel> ReturnViewModel = new List<RoleViewModel>();

    IList<Role> AllRoles = PermServ.GetAllRoles();

    foreach (var CurRole in AllRoles)
    {
        ReturnViewModel.Add(new RoleViewModel(CurRole));
    }
```

Its pretty simple code simply taking the Data Object and converting it into a ViewModel. I was wondering if there was a way to do this better? - Maybe with Linq?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the top of my head (not by dev machine).

```
IList<RoleViewModel> returnViewModel = PermServ.GetAllRoles()
                                        .Select(x => new RoleViewModel(x))
                                        .ToList();
```

Comment: 'IList<Role> AllRoles =' should this be 'IList<RoleViewModel> AllRoles ='

Answer (score 6):

```
var returnViewModel  = (from n in PermServ.GetAllRoles()
                       select new RoleViewModel(n)).ToList();
```

Comment: Should be Select new RoleViewModel(n)).ToList(); No?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays) handle your conversions.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Role, RoleModel>();
IList<RoleViewModel> returnViewModel = 
   Mapper.Map<IList<Role>, IList<RoleViewModel>>(PermServ.GetAllRoles());
```